# ASP.NET Web API index.html does not load; Server Error in '/' Application, The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api).

When I build the solution the index.html page would not show up and I get this error: Server Error in '/' Application.
I'm not sure how to enable detailed error reporting.

This is my Web.config page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IIS Express shows it as `http://localhost:11527/`

Comment: Did you look in the project references page to see if all the references could be found?

Comment: My project reference page is empty. I don't think there are any references for this tutorial.

Comment: I would think you would need the references listed in the namespaces, like this one: http://i.imgur.com/SGB3rrK.png  (It would explain the missing resource message).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are accessing it like `http://localhost:11527/index.html`. Note that this was created with an Empty project template and so there is no MVC and so you cannot expect a default view showing up and so you would need to explicitly mention `index.html` in your url.

Comment: I have add `app.UseMvc()`, but not load index.html as default, how to do that in Startup.cs file?